# trying to increment and assign a variable in single step in python3

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
a = 90
z  =0
z =a+1
print(z)

# I want do the both steps in one step but I am getting syntax error 
a = 90
z = a++
print(z)

**error 
    z = a++**

          ^
SyntaxError:
 invalid syntax
```

Can anyone explain why? And how to do the increment using ++?

Answer (score 1):

**`a++`** does not support in python. Such as integers are **immutable** in python. `z = a++` is invalid syntax. you can use `a++` as `a += 1`.

```
 a = 90
 a+= 1
 z = a
 print(z)
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe there is `x++` inpython. I know how it is used, and how it adds one to a number, but python does not support this. So instead you should use `x+=1`. That's fixing your syntax error. But for your question about doing it in one step, do this:

```
a = 90
z = a + 1
```

This works, but using `x++` is not supported in python and is not more effective tha simply adding one to `a` and assigning it to `z`.